# "Call-time pass-by-reference has been removed"

Tags: php, wordpress, dotcloud

I'm trying to deploy Wordpress on Dotcloud using this repo but there is an error that appears in the logs:

```
18:59:19: [www.0] Running postinstall script...
18:59:21: [www.0] PHP Fatal error:  Call-time pass-by-reference has been removed in /home/dotcloud/rsync-1353715101184/dotcloud-scripts/feed-wp-config.php on line 86
```

Looking at [line 86 in feed-wp-config.php](https://github.com/qpleple/wordpress-on-dotcloud/blob/master/dotcloud-scripts/feed-wp-config.php#L86), it reads:

```
$content = preg_replace('/(define\(\'' . $property . '\', \')(.*)(\'\);)/', '${1}' . $value . '${3}', $content, -1, &$count);
```

When I go to the Wordpress start page it says, "There doesn't seem to be a wp-config.php file. I need this before we can get started."

I've [cross-posted this to the repo's Github issue tracker](https://github.com/qpleple/wordpress-on-dotcloud/issues/2), but as there hasn't yet been a response I'm posting it here as well in hopes that someone knows the answer.

Answer (score 13):

Replace  `&$count` with just `$count`. `&` meant you want variable to be passed by reference, not value:

[Documentation says](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php)

> There is no reference sign on a function call - only on function
>   definitions. Function definitions alone are enough to correctly pass
>   the argument by reference. As of PHP 5.3.0, you will get a warning
>   saying that "call-time pass-by-reference" is deprecated when you use &
>   in foo(&$a);.

So if you want to pass variable by reference to the function, you should use `&` in function declaration:

This now should be done that way:

```
// right
function foo(&$var) {
...
}

foo($foo);
```

but not that way (as you get this warning):

```
function foo($var) {
...
}

foo(&$foo);   // <--- wrong
```

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone! I removed the '&' and now it works!

Answer (score 3):

Remove the & sign from the `&$count` at the end of the line.

<del>Please bear in mind, that this is a core hack in wordpress, and it will be lost on an update.</del>.

Comment: Updating Wordpress will not change the `wp-config.php`. Is that what you meant?

Comment: It's not the main `wp-config.php` file, it's `feed-wp-config.php`. Is that also skipped when updating?

Comment: the file `feed-wp-config.php` is not part of Wordpress, it's a script that edits `wp-config.php` so it will not be lost.